# Decimal to binary function in Python using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I am new in Python and trying to write a binary-to-decimal converted function like below

```
def decimaltobinary(n):
    if n > 1:
        decimaltobinary(n//2)
    print(n%2,end='')
    #return n%2

decimaltobinary(4)
```

This works perfectly fine. Now the question is when I am modifying it as below, it doesn't give me correct result -

```
def decimaltobinary(n):
    if n > 1:
        decimaltobinary(n//2)
    #print(n%2,end='')
    return n%2

a=decimaltobinary(4)
print(a)
```

Am I missing something with the return statement? Any pointer will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be careful with your return statements. Try this:

```
def decimaltobinary(n):
    def _dtb(n, lst):
        if n <= 0:
            return lst
        lst.append(n&1)
        return _dtb(n>>1, lst)
    return ''.join(map(str, reversed(_dtb(n, list()))))
print(decimaltobinary(19))
```

**Output:**

```
10011
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second example returned value from `decimaltobinary` in `if` is completely ignored.

What you need to do is assign the returned value to a variable and then return it together with `n%2`.

Try this:

```
def decimaltobinary(n):
x = ''
if n > 1:
    x = decimaltobinary(n//2)
#print(n%2,end='')
return str(x) + '' + str(n%2)

a=decimaltobinary(4)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you are printing on each iteration of the recursive method.
On the second example you're smashing the **return** statement.

You can see here:

```
def decimaltobinary(n):
    if n > 1:
        print('Making recursion for (n): ', n)
        decimaltobinary(n//2)
    print('Return for (n): ', n, ', result: ', n%2)
    return n%2

a=decimaltobinary(4)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
Making recursion for (n):  4
Making recursion for (n):  2
Return for (n):  1 , result:  1
Return for (n):  2 , result:  0
Return for (n):  4 , result:  0
0
```